# Issue with pushing UIViewController on UITabbarController

Tags: iphone

I have implemented UINavigationController and UITabbarController with each other. I am able to see Navigation bar and Tab bar along with UIViewController.

Problem is when I push any other UIViewController on this controller,that viewcontroller get pushed but Tabbar get disappeared.

Is there any provision to persist that UITabBar along the stack????

below is code I am referring

```
UIViewController* cont1 = [UIViewController alloc]init];
UIViewController* cont2 = [UIViewController alloc]init];

[tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:cont1,cont2,nil]];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it the other way around.
Place an `UINavigationController` in each of the `UIViewController` in the  `UITabbarController`.

Answer (score 0):

```
YourViewController *viewController = [YourViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
UINavigationController *controller = [UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController] autorelease];
controller.title = @"something";
controller.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"xx"];
tabController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:controller];
```

then you can push sub view controllers into navigation controller with tab bar persistent at the bottom of the screen.